# SAML SSO With .NET - What is this error from Salesforce?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, .net

I am trying to use MVC.NET as an SSO IdP

I cannot understand the reason of the error message I get.

The result I get from salesforce says:

> 1. Validating the Signature
>
>    Is the response signed? true
>
>    Is the assertion signed? false
>
>    The signature in the response is valid
>
>    Is the correct certificate supplied in the keyinfo? true
>
>    Signature or certificate problems   **The reference in the
>      response signature #_5d5ac6c does not match the ID**

The assertion id is _5d5ac6c

Base64 Response is :

```
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
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, this is the decoded response (via the excellent [SAML 2.0 Debugger](https://rnd.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/saml2debug/debug.php)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<q1:Response xmlns:q1="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" InResponseTo="_2busaOfSBy_cEadYXmXNmVhaYbTnaUhHNx7t8W6gYtRQJl0ATUEDkVhnPUtj8Z5iHCcTmjuq_BC_DyDm_Sfg4RTtiX27TPJZkqlHMyoeKOrTLjGW2XD5VQwdM0vK4ZdfORt6Nw7FFGeNoJgSFbr6dVBfrbQy6yEhqJthD4KhGE1h4cJtzmO9TQ_oQLovPM93YaLo1sD8ASUm1tFkUqemqwgC6QEa7rQ" Destination="https://identillect--DevSandbox.cs17.my.salesforce.com?so=00Dg0000006HYHL">
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://www.t-caret.com/</Issuer>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <Reference URI="#_5d5ac6c">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                   <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <DigestValue>2FJHYVjg+nwRVwn5phFmjCQ3GTM=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>oDh2ne7P61B89nBVEXMMb7WgBzLYJDhK7ftmVPkFuv3z/38WtkR7apZj7LT1ywU+8+PGiAZr4+fzuKN9wmcbkXGIB8hb0ZpI9DCbxbEjyE3N7ZeOzZdrrGr2ASuUvET6dGTduBh4HoSD0nSwe7mhXREFcQJnAXbob3AhFNN9EPg=</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
                <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <q1:Status>
        <q1:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </q1:Status>
    <Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Version="2.0" ID="_5d5ac6c" IssueInstant="2013-12-09T00:48:07.0503429Z">
        <Issuer>https://www.t-caret.com/</Issuer>
        <Subject>
            <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent">tsadigov@gmail.com</NameID>
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2013-12-09T01:43:07.0503429Z" Recipient="https://identillect--DevSandbox.cs17.my.salesforce.com?so=00Dg0000006HYHL"/>
            </SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions NotBefore="2013-12-09T00:43:07.0503429Z" NotOnOrAfter="2013-12-09T01:43:07.0503429Z">
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>https://devsandbox-identillect.cs17.force.com/</Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2013-12-09T00:43:07.0503429Z" SessionIndex="2025989804">
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:X509</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
        <AttributeStatement>
            <Attribute Name="urn:FirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <AttributeValue>Tural</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="urn:LastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <AttributeValue>Sadigov</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="urn:Age" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <AttributeValue>27</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <AttributeValue>ceo@salesforce.uk</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="urn:dk:company:attribute:Role" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <AttributeValue>CEO</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="urn:dk:company:attribute:Role" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <AttributeValue>CTO</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="dk:gov:saml:attribute:AssuranceLevel" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <AttributeValue>3</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="organization_id">
                <AttributeValue>00Dg0000006HYHL</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="portal_id">
                <AttributeValue>060b00000000Ts7</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="siteurl">
                <AttributeValue>https://devsandbox-identillect.cs17.force.com/</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeStatement>
    </Assertion>
</q1:Response>
```

Now, you'll notice that the `<Signature>` is a child of the `<Response>`, but it refers to the `<Assertion>`. If the `<Signature>` refers to the `<Assertion>`, it should be a child of the `<Assertion>`; if it is a child of the `<Response>`, then it should refer to the `<Response>`.

Comment: thanks @metadaddy a lot, that was a direct answer to my question. I am on the next step I hope you will show the right path http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/bypass-salesforce-login-to-sso-identity-provider