# How do I bypass Salesforce login to do SSO with Identity Provider

Tags: customer-portal, single-sign-on, saml

I am integrating an ASP.MVC site with Salesforce. The front end is an existing ASP site with iframes in some places that lead to Salesforce. ASP side is also the Identity Provider. I have set up Salesforce Identity Provider and it appears in the login page where I select my identity provider and if there's a session in ASP side it automatically logs into Salesforce also. My problem is that I don't want the user to see the Salesforce login page and click my identity provider. I need some way to tell Salesforce to automatically use my identity provider when there is a guest access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using Salesforce Communities:

[Edit the Community's Login Page](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=networks_customize_login.htm&siteLang=en_US), and ensure that your SAML IdP is the only selected login option:

[image]

Now users will be automatically directed to the IdP for login, instead of seeing the Salesforce Community login page.

### For Internal Users

You need to create a **My Domain** (see [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_name_overview.htm&language=en_US)). My Domain gives your org a custom login URL, for example, `https://company.my.salesforce.com/`.

Once you have My Domain, configure the [Login Page Branding](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_name_login_id_prov.htm&language=en_US) so the SAML IdP is the only selected Authentication Service:

[image]

Now users will be automatically directed to the IdP for login, instead of seeing the Salesforce login page.